# Floating LogScale histogram

Tags: histograms, logarithmic-scale

I have a histogram that I represent on a base 10 semi-log scale, and I need to fix the plot range. If I set the lower bound for the logarithmic axis, the histogram bins do not stretch downward fully. A minimal working example of the problematic code is:

```mathematica
Histogram[
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^4],
  Automatic,
  "PDF",
  PlotRange->{All,{-7,0}}, PlotTheme->"Scientific",ScalingFunctions->{None,"Log10"}]
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image]

So you see the bins do not stretch all the way downward.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems buggy to me. A quick and dirty fix is something like `Histogram[...] /. Rectangle[{x1_, _}, rest___] :> Rectangle[{x1, -7}, rest]` to replace the bottom coordinates of all the bars with the correct value.

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks for the answer! However, this does not work, at least not for me. It even seems to reflect the bins about the y-axis. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: I am not sure that `PlotRange -> {All, {-7, 0}}` makes sense to me. Shouldn't you specify the plot range according to the original values, rather than their logarithm, i.e. `PlotRange -> {All, {1*^-7, 1}}`? Your version doesn't work well in MMA 12.3.1 on Win10-64. Having said that, changing the plot range doesn't remove your problem, but setting it to `Automatic`, or using @Lukas' proposed workaround works for me.

Comment: @JonasB which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @LukasLang I'm using MMA 10.1. The thing is, I need the plotrange to be fixed at these values, since I will compare different histograms on the same scale, and the one with the lowest value has these ranges. So I cannot just omit the PlotRange command and let MMA determine it automatically

Answer (score 2):

With v13.1 it is necessary to omit specifying the `PlotRange`

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

Histogram[
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^4],
 Automatic, "PDF",
 PlotRange -> {All, {-7, 0}},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log10"}]
```

[image]

The above is clearly wrong.

```
SeedRandom[1234];

Histogram[
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^4],
 Automatic, "PDF",
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log10"}]With v13.1 it is necessary to omit specifying the `PlotRange`
```

[image]

**EDIT:** However, you can specify the `PlotRange` as either `All` or `Full`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I really need the range to be fixed at 1 and 10^-7, so I cannot let MMA choose it for itself. I'm using MMA 10.1 on an Ubuntu 20 machine.